# How do I create tags for VB.NET files with Exuberant Ctags?

Tags: vb.net, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

We use .NET here at work and our project is a little mixed, with some VB and C#. Exuberant Ctags generates C# tags just fine for me following [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20121114112215/https://arun.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/c-and-vim/). However, I have yet to be able to figure out how to get it to generate tags for my VB.NET code. The only article I've found that was somewhat helpful is [this one](http://www.rutherfurd.net/2003/apr/17/adding-support-for-visual-basic-to-exuberent-ctags/). But at 2003 it ranks just a few years old. The first thing I noticed is that this line:

```
--langmap=vb:.bas.cls.ctl.frm.vbs
```

Is wrong, and also old. I changed it to read:

```
--langmap=vb:.vb
```

That improved my results slightly, but it still doesn't seem to generate the expected behavior (e.g. when I `:set tag=tags` and do ^] or g] on a function call or parameter, it has no tags).

This is what my `ctags.cnf` file looks like (and I have verified that it's being used):

```
--langdef=vb
--langmap=vb:.vb
--regex-vb=/^(Public|Private|\b)[ \t]*Sub[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\2/s,subroutine/i
--regex-vb=/^(Public|Private|\b)[ \t]*Function[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\2/f,function/i
--regex-vb=/^(Public|Private)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[ \t]+As[ \t]+/\2/v,variable/i
--regex-vb=/^(Public|Private|\b)[ \t]*Const[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[ \t]+(As|=)[ \t]+/\2/c,const/i
--regex-vb=/^(Public|\b)[ \t]*Property[ \t]*(Get|Let|Set)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\3/n,name/i
--regex-vb=/^(Public|Private|\b)[ \t]*Enum[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\2/e,enum/i
--regex-vb=/^([a-zA-Z_]+):/\1/l,label/i
--recurse
--exclude="bin"
--exclude="obj"
--fields=+ianmzS
--extra=+fq
--vb-kinds=cn
```

Any clue what I need to do to get proper support?

### Edit:

This is a snip from my tag file:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8 //
Application.Designer.vb .\My Project\Application.Designer.vb    1;" kind:F  line:1
Application.Designer.vb .\Nuts\My Project\Application.Designer.vb   1;" kind:F  line:1
AssemblyInfo.vb .\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    1;" kind:F  line:1
AssemblyInfo.vb .\Nuts\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb   1;" kind:F  line:1
AttachmentHandler.vb    .\Utilities\AttachmentHandler.vb    1;" kind:F  line:1
```

While my CS codebase generates tags like this:

```
SomeModel   .\Client\Views\Models\Namespace\SomeModel.cs    /^    public class SomeModel$/;"    kind:c  line:12 namespace:Views.Models.SomeModel    access:public
```

Comment: Did you update your vimrc to let it know about the new language? http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/extend.html

Comment: What command do you use to generate your `tags` file? Do you get errors? Is the `tags` file empty? is it correctly populated?

Comment: @romainl, It's not empty but it doesn't appear to be correctly populated. I have my ctags.cnf file in the base directory of the project, and if I read the `man` page correctly it automatically uses that if present. When I ran `ctags --options=ctags.cnf` it gave me a warning about the language vb already existing.

Comment: @embedded.kyle it looks like that's specifically the taglist plugin, and not the built-in tag behavior. Yet I have used that plugin, so that link should be quite helpful.

Comment: Isn't `ctags.cnf` supposed to be in your `$HOME` directory?

Comment: If you take a look at the [manual](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html), ctags.cnf is fine in the local directory... if you're running on Windows, which I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you follow a zero-indent coding convention your regular expressions won't work ;)

Try:

```
 // Note the extra [ \t]* right after ^
 --regex-vb=/^[ \t]*(Public|Private|\b)[ \t]*Sub[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\2/s,subroutine/i
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working configuration, extracted from my `~/.ctags`, based on that from OP's and applying accepted answer edit.

I had to remove the label matcher as this prevented all Sub/Function matches (not sure why) and replace the `(Public|Private|\b)` with `(Public|Private)?` to get it to optionally match access modifiers (else it didn't match any without these modifiers for me).

```
--exclude="bin"
--exclude="obj"
--langdef=vb
--langmap=vb:.vb
--regex-vb=/^[ \t]*(Public|Private)?[ \t]*Sub[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\2/s,subroutine/i
--regex-vb=/^[ \t]*(Public|Private)?[ \t]*Function[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\2/f,function/i
--regex-vb=/^[ \t]*(Public|Private)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[ \t]+As[ \t]+/\2/v,variable/i
--regex-vb=/^[ \t]*(Public|Private)?[ \t]*Const[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[ \t]+(As|=)[ \t]+/\2/c,const/i
--regex-vb=/^[ \t]*(Public)?[ \t]*Property[ \t]*(Get|Let|Set)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\3/n,name/i
--regex-vb=/^[ \t]*(Public|Private)?[ \t]*Enum[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\2/e,enum/i
#--regex-vb=/^[ \t]*([a-zA-Z_]+):/\1/l,label/i
--recurse
--fields=+ianmzS
--extra=+fq
--vb-kinds=cn
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response!

maybe the \b it's a pcre vs posix issue? 

also, why define c,s, v, e, n if you only enable vb-kinds=cn ? maybe that will be confusing.

just some thoughts.

I modified your script, it seems to do the job.